# ShinyApps.io issue: there is no package called ‘askpass’

Tags: r, shinydashboard, shinyapps

I am attempting to publish my first shiny app and it give me the following error when I try to follow the instructions on the [R Studio site](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/shinyapps.html). Tried downloading the 'askpass' package but it failed. Any guidance would be appreciated.

```js
rsconnect::setAccountInfo(name='******', token='*******************', secret='**********************************')
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘askpass’
```

Comment: install.packages("askpass") does work for me, what makes it failed for you?

Comment: Hi, I made this work on another machine. It seems, it's to do with limitations my work machine.